# How to find previous and next index in an numeric array with PHP

Tags: php, pagination

I wish I have a smart and clean way to find the name of a page in an numeric array and get the previous and next pages, also testing if it is not the first or the last page (for it would not have a previous and a next page).

I've seen solutions with `while` and `next` and `prev` functions and others subtracting and adding 1 in a `foreach` loop. But I confess I'm really confused.

For example:

```
$keys = array('page1', 'page2', 'page3');
```

Thanks for any light.

Answer (score -1):

This may help someone:

```
$keys=array('page1','page2','page3');
$prev=$next='';
$page='page2';
$current=array_search($page,$keys);
if($current+1<=count($keys)-1) $older=$keys[$current+1];
if($current-1>=1) $newer=$keys[$current-1];
die("\n$prev,$next");
```